# How can I load multiple tar images using nerdctl? (containerd)

Tags: docker, xargs, containerd, nerdctl

There are around 10 container image files on the current directory, and I want to load them to my Kubernetes cluster that is using containerd as CRI.

```
[root@test tmp]# ls -1
test1.tar
test2.tar
test3.tar
...
```

I tried to load them at once using xargs but got the following result:

```
[root@test tmp]# ls -1 | xargs nerdctl load -i
unpacking image1:1.0 (sha256:...)...done
[root@test tmp]#
```

The first tar file was successfully loaded, but the command exited and the remaining tar files were not processed.

I have confirmed the command `nerdctl load -i` succeeded with exit code 0.

```
[root@test tmp]# nerdctl load -i test1.tar
unpacking image1:1.0 (sha256:...)...done
[root@test tmp]# echo $?
0
```

Does anyone know the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual `ls` command piped to `xargs` is seen as a single argument where file names are separated by null bytes (shortly said... see for example [this article](https://medium.com/@stefansilverio/what-happens-when-you-type-ls-l-in-a-shell-1c3f210c6bbf) for a better in-depth analyze). If your version of `xargs` supports it, you can use the `-0` option to take this into account:

```sh
ls -1 | xargs -0 nerdctl load -i
```

Meanwhile, this is not really safe and you should see why [it's not a good idea to loop over `ls` output in your shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

I would rather transform the above to the following command:

```sh
for f in *.tar; do
  nerdctl load -i "$f"
done
```